# How i can connect from localhost to android emulator?

Tags: android, adb, loopback

Many people ask about "How get the connect from a emulator to localhost". I am asking about a reverse issue. I created a tiny http server in android app. I know his ip address and want to connect from my chrome browser to the app. If i use my a phone it is no problem, because app use "outer" ip, but in local net wifi. When i use a emulator on a development machine and open in browser ip 10.0.2.15 then can not get access to app in emulator. I tryed any ways - loopback, forward ... all is not working.

Comment: Please see the section entitled "Using Network Redirection" in the emulator documentation at http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkinglimitations if that does not work for you, then restate the question giving the specific difficulty you encounter in following those instructions.

Comment: @T-Rush reverted your edit, as you highlighted the question which was **not** being asked, something likely to lead to more off-target answers.